# Gazebo ROS package structure

Tags: gazebo, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started to learn ROS using Lunar distribution on an Ubuntu 16.04.

I need to use Gazebo with ROS to do my academic exercises.

Reading the [Tutorial: Using roslaunch to start Gazebo, world files and URDF models](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch&cat=connect_ros), on section, **Creating your own Gazebo ROS Package**, I've found this text:

*"Everything concerning your robot's model and description is located, as per ROS standards, in a package named /MYROBOT_description ..."*

I have tried to find those ROS standards but I don't know where they are.

Is there any standard to add a robot to a ROS package? Where can I find more information about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291177/gazebo-ros-package-structure/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a standard for package layout, but for naming.

If there is a standard, it would be [REP-144 - ROS Package Naming](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0144.html). Under section [Naming Rules]([REP-144 - ROS Package Naming](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0144.html#naming-rules), it says:

> Special Suffixes:
>
> - a package containing the URDF and meshes of a robot should be named `<name_of_the_robot>_description`, e.g `pr2_description`

So this basically says: packages with robot models should be called `X_description`.

That is most likely what the tutorial you linked refers to.

---

Edit:

> Thanks. I'm lost with this. It's hard to start learning ROS.

Note btw: I just referred to the REP as it's a convenient document. The custom / convention of naming pkgs with robot models in them *description packages* has existed since long before `REP-144` was written.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-05-15**:
Ok. Thanks. I'm lost with this. It's hard to start learning ROS.

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-05-15**:
I have followed the tutorial, but when I run: me@myComputer:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch MYROBOT_gazebo MYROBOT.launch. I get: RLException: [MYROBOT.launch] is neither a launch file in package [MYROBOT_gazebo] nor is [MYROBOT_gazebo] a launch file name. Any idea?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
No idea. But just a comment: you're not required to use `MYROBOT` everywhere. It's just a placeholder for whatever name you'd actually want/need. It's similar to the `X` I used everywhere in my answer.